# AWS State Machine external manipulation

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have a file upload pattern which would benefit from the use of a State Machine.  What I would like is for an external service via the sdk (java) to create an execution.  I would then like this same service to be able to act on this execution to cause a state change.

For example, a request is made to upload a file to our service. We then prime the State machine in a kind of holding state (with timeout).
The user then uploads a file through the same service, on completion we would like to interact with that same state machine to move it to its next state.

All the patterns Ive found (Callback, Activities) involve the state machine initiating that interaction, however our pattern involves the Service initiating it.
Is there an approach I could use, or does it fall outside the nature of a State Machine?

One possibility could be to listen for a unique event on event bridge perhaps - but I cant find a method for doing that

Another possibility is to have some mechanism in which a Process which kicks off a State Machine with a Task Activity could also get the Task Token for that particular state machine.  But I dont know if this is possible either

Comment: Is the file upload the first step?

Comment: In our case, no, requesting a tokenised url to upload to is the first step

Answer (score 1):

An [EventBridge optimised integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html) task with the [Callback Pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token) can send the task token in an event.  The State Machine execution pauses.  A rule lets the service receive the events.  When ready to return control to the execution, the service makes a [SendTaskSuccess](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_SendTaskSuccess.html) SDK call with the token and an arbitrary payload.  The execution resumes.

---

Alternative:  The service provides the client a S3 presigned URL for the file upload.  Upon file upload, S3 raises an event.  An EventBridge rule invokes the Step Function execution when this occurs.  The execution starts.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately its not quite the use case Im after, the EventBridge can invoke execution, however I find no mechanism where a State Machine can listen on the Eventbridge for a targeted event, which is more what I was looking for.
As such we are moving to a DynamoDb/Lambda model.